# Update but in button_click event

Tags: c#, sql

```
con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("update Department_Master  Dept_code='"+txtDepartment.Text+"'where  " ,con);
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("update Designation_Master  'DE_1','DS_1','" + txtDesignation.Text + "'", con);
    SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("update into Position_Master values('" + var1 + "','" + var2 + "',@n,'" + txtHietrchy.Text + "')", con);
    cmd3.Parameters.Add("@n", SqlDbType.Int).Value = n;
    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
    m++;

    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();
```

I want to update three tables based on primary key,each table have this primary key as forgein key.
There are three tables

this is the primary key autogeneration code....

```
    txtDesignation.Enabled = true;
    con.Open();
    int[] a = new int[100];
    int i = 0;
    String st = "select  substring(Dept_code ,4,10)as DE_ID from Department_Master";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(st, con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            a[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dr["DE_ID"].ToString());
            i++;
        }
        int cv = a.Max();
        var1 = "DE_" + Convert.ToString(cv + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        var1 = "DE_1";
    }
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert into Department_Master values('" + var1 + "', '" + txtDepartment.Text + "')", con);
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //<..department end.........>

    int[] b= new int[100];
    int j = 0;
    string st1 = "select substring(Dsgn_Code,4,10)as DS_ID from Designation_Master";
    SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(st1,con);
    DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
    da1.Fill(ds1);
    DataTable dt1 = ds1.Tables[0];
    if (ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr1 in dt1.Rows)
        {
            b[j] = Convert.ToInt32(dr1["DS_ID"].ToString());
            j++;
        }
        int cv1 = b.Max();
        var2 = "DS_" + Convert.ToString(cv1 + 1);
    }
    else 
    {
        var2 = "DS_1";
    }
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into Designation_Master values('"+var1+"','" + var2 + "', '" + txtDesignation.Text + "')", con);
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //<........designation end................>

    SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("insert into Position_Master values('"+var1+"','"+var2+"',@m,'"+txtHietrchy.Text+"')", con);
    cmd3.Parameters.Add("@m", SqlDbType.Int).Value = m;
    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
    m++;

    //<.....position end......>
```

Comment: In first table  i have two columns,second table i have three columns,third table have four columns ok.based on the primary key in the first table ,which is forgein key in other tables i need to update the data.each table have it primary keys which are auto genarated FROM DE_1,DE_2,....,ETC. I need to update the table values based on their primary keys.

Comment: Please find my edited comments in answer in few mins.

Answer (score 0):

While your question is not clear, I would like to post a few comments here.

The update queries look incomplete. They may result in SQL exception.
Queries in cmd1 and cmd2 doesn't have set. First query contains 'where' with no constraints.
3rd Query appears like insert and you have placed update in it.

Above all, you are directly placing a textbox's content in your query.
SQL INJECTION is very much possible here.

My first advice is review your queries. Try to work on them in SQL server and if it works there bring them to C#.

And then, please avoid such inline queries. They are dangerous. Use parameters and Stored procedures.

**Edited**

To use the primary key generated in one table in the next insert/update, use @@identity, or SCOPE_IDENTITY().

For example, in your case,

the first query would be like this.

INSERT INTO Department_Master (....) VALUES (....)

Let's say it returns a Identity as a primary key (department_id)

the second query should go like this.

INSERT INTO Designation_Master (..., department_id,...) Values (..., @@identity, ...)

Remember, they should all fall in the same scope/ same connection.

Comment: please look at my edited question which i re-posted and provide me a solution

Comment: Looks like you are calculating var2 and assuming that's the new key inserted in department master. You are using var2 in other two inserts. From what you are describing the code should work. Where do you find issue?

Comment: Yeah why i sent u that auto generation code because ,thats how it should get updated .I dnt know the code to write for update.

Comment: if i update the value based on primary key,all the values should be updated and with that primary key i can be able to update my other values related to that also

Comment: Check if this link gives you any clue. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp